# tbb::concurrent_multiset/concurrent_set crashes when using unsafe_erase() to erase begin()

Tags: c++, tbb

My code is as follows, I use .begin() to get the first element in the set, and it can be obtained correctly, but using .unsafe_erase(iterator) will often crash. Of course, the first line（WriteGuard) is a write lock.
[image]

[image]

I don't know why this happens, can someone give me some suggestions, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

concurrent_set/concurrent_multiset supports concurrent insertion and traversal but not concurrent erasure.
you can refer to the below link for more details:
https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/0.5.0/oneTBB/containers/concurrent_set_cls.html

From oneTBB 2021, the implementation of concurrent_set has changed internally. you can try using the latest version of oneTBB (2021.4).

You can download the oneTBB standalone component from the below link:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/oneapi-standalone-components.html

You can also try with opensource oneTBB

https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/releases/tag/v2021.4.0